# Jquery focusout on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two divs, one called "mainDesign" and a box called "div1".

When "div1" is clicked, focusin is called and the border-color changes.

"div1" can only focusout if "mainDesign" is clicked.

The script works but "mainDesign" needs to be clicked twice in order for it to work, after it has focused out, the script works perfectly.

Any ideas?
Code: http://jsfiddle.net/v3DWf/14/

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrote using mousedown and stopPropagation(): http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/v3DWf/20/

Haha, looks like Royce Feng beat me to it.

---

<s>I removed focusout(), as it seems to be an unnecessary step...</s>

Is this acceptable?: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/v3DWf/15/

EDIT: switched the functions around, seems to work as intended now: http://jsfiddle.net/patrickmarabeas/v3DWf/17/

Comment: Thanks Patrick, works great. But if you click twice, it stops working :/

Comment: I don't think that is quite what he wants. I assume he doesn't want the border to go away if they click on the "div1", which it will with your code since "div1" is inside of "mainDesign"

Comment: It now loses focus when clicking outside of #mainDesign :/

Comment: Your edited answer will attach the focusout event when div1 is first clicked, so when div1 is blurred by any means, it will lose the border.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch to using `.mousedown()` and stopping propagation in the inner one.

http://jsfiddle.net/v3DWf/18/

Comment: works great too! Never thought of using mousedown for both divs. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#div1").focusin(function() {
    $(this).css("border-color","#ff9900");
});

$("#mainDesign").mousedown(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!$("#div1").is(":focus"))
            $("#div1").css("border-color","#999999");        
    }, 100);
});
```

The timeout is necessary because the mousedown will fire before the div is blurred.

Comment: same problem. the div needs two clicks to focusout when focused.

Comment: EDIT: sorry my bad, this script works perfect, thanks. Cant vote up because I need 15 reputation -.-

Comment: @Max6701 If this is the answer you want to accept, click the checkbox below the vote up/down buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Well the problem is that you've nested the .mousedown() event within the .focusout() event.

So what is happening here is that when the focusout event is triggered, you are then attaching the .mousedown event to the mainDesign div. Let me re-iterate that again, the .mousedown event will NOT be attached until the focusout event has triggered.

Then once the .mousedown event is attached, the next time you mousedown in the mainDesign div, the event will fire which is why it is currently taking you two clicks.

So the easiest solution is to simply get rid of the .focusout event.